# Large File Uploads (> 4GB) with nginx and php-fpm

Tags: php, linux, nginx

I am trying to upload large files with nginx and php-fpm and my own PHP script.
For files larger than 4 GB the PHP upload fails. I get a HTTP 200 response with my error message from PHP.
print_r($_FILES) shows me:

```
    [file] => Array
    (
        [name] => foo.dat
        [type] => 
        [tmp_name] => 
        [error] => 3
        [size] => 0
    )
```

According to http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php error 3 means:

> UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL
>   Value: 3;
>   The uploaded file was only partially uploaded.

All the data gets sent to nginx and yet php says "size=0".
I tried the upload in an HTML form and as XMLHttpRequest with Google Chrome and Firefox, as well as with a little upload program in Java. So an error on the client side or the connection is unlikely.

According to Chrome Network Inspector all data gets sent correctly, the content length in the request header is correct. After the data is sent I get the server response within 5 seconds, so a timeout is unlikely.

My nginx configuration:

```
client_max_body_size 8000m;
client_body_buffer_size 512k;

fastcgi_buffers 512 32k;
fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 128k;
fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
fastcgi_max_temp_file_size 0;
fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
fastcgi_send_timeout 18000;
fastcgi_read_timeout 1800;
```

And the php.ini for the php-fpm instance:

```
upload_max_filesize = 8000M
post_max_size = 8000M
max_input_time = 1800
max_execution_time = 300
memory_limit = 512M
;upload_tmp_dir = // not specified, which means system default according to the php docs. That's /tmp on my machine
```

The nginx and php-fpm error log say nothing about this. I have restarted nginx and php-fpm multiple times already.

I am running nginx/1.6.0 with php 5.5.11 on Debian 6 64bit.

I will test this on a 2nd server now since I'm thinking the issue might be with Debian and outside of nginx/php-fpm.
Any ideas how to debug this further?

**UPDATE 1:**

There is enough disk space. To test for partition and/or permission problems I just created an upload folder under
a) the same mount point as the web root
b) and with the same user as php-fpm is running

so simply: upload_tmp_dir = /home/myuser/upload
and I restarted php-fpm

The problem is still the same, I get an HTTP 200 with php error=3 for the file upload. Smaller files can be uploaded and appear temporarily in the new temp folder.

**FIX**
After updating to the latest php 5.6 version the error is gone. I am using the same php.ini file with that version, so it's probably a changed default setting or a fixed bug in php.

Comment: Do you have free space on server for this big files in temp folder? May be you have limit for default temp folder. You can try change upload_tmp_dir to folder with free space more than 4 Gb.

Comment: Yes there was enough space under /tmp.
I added the answer above as an update for better formatting.